# Prove that an entire and bounded function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, entire-functions

Let $f$ an entire function. Suppose that $|f(z)|\leq 1 + |z|^{1-\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

I need to prove this statement without usinge Liouville's theorem.

I'm practically lost. At first, I repeated almost all the proof of the theorem.

Comment: You are basically reproducing the proof of Liouville's Theorem!

Comment: If $R=|b-a|+1$, how can $R \to \infty$ with $a,b$ fixed?

Comment: Well, I'm very lost in how to do it, so I thought the same argument could work. Nonetheless, for some days I have think in the problem, but I could not fine any other way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is entire and that for each $z \in \mathbb{C}$ we have $|f(z)| \leq 1+ |z|^{1-\alpha}$ for an $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

Fix $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$. We will show that $f'(z_0) = 0$. Let $C_R = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | |z-z_0| = R \}$. By Cauchy's formula we have

\begin{align*}|f'(z_0)| &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \bigg| \int_{C_R} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2} \, dx \bigg| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \max_{z \in C_R} \frac{|f(z)|}{|z-z_0|^2} \ell(C_R) \\
& \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} 2\pi R \frac{1}{R^2} \max_{\theta \in [0, 2\pi]} (1+|z_0 + Re^{i\theta}|^{1-\alpha}) \\
& \leq \frac{1}{R}(1+|z_0+R|^{1-\alpha}),
\end{align*}

where we used that $z=z_0 + Re^{i\theta}$ for $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$ on $C_R$. Since $f$ is entire, $R$ may be chosen arbitrarily. We let $R \rightarrow \infty$ and conclude that $f'(z_0)=0$.

In conclusion we have $f'(z)=0$ for alle $z \in \mathbb{C}$, which means that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Please read the body of the question, and not only the title.

Comment: I have now edited the argument so that it fits the question specifically.

Comment: Thank you @Fenris. Your answer helped me.